# Ctrl + C is not working on JqGrid when inline edit is possible

Tags: jqgrid, cell, edit, copy-paste, ctrl

I used jqGrid and make the cell editable by

'cellEdit' : true,
'cellsubmit' : 'remote'

After that, I can't copy the cell from jQgrid table by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

If disable the cellEdit, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> works.

How can I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> with Edit Cell.

Comment: Please, describe which version of jqGrid is used? In [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net) this work. In case you use Guriddo jqGrid and it is not working as expected,  please provide a example demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing some font files in CSS.

When font files is missing, I found the same issue like you.

Please check the console in browser.